# TextView gets cut after Rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, textview

I would like to rotate a `TextView` 90 degrees. This works, however, the TextView gets "cut" in the y-axis (namely to the screen width, see screenshot).

How could I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:rotation="90"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="256"
        android:textSize="50mm"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I am sure that the TextView gets cut, not my Layout.

Comment: Remove   `android:gravity="center"` in the textview and try.

Comment: it didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: That was not to fix the problem, it was just not necessary.       To fix the problem add `android:paddingBottom="200dp"` in the textview

Comment: now it is also cut in the x-axis (200dp on the left side)

Comment: Also remove android:gravity="center" in the linearlayout

Comment: what about reducing `android:textSize` ?

Comment: that would be an option, but I need such a big TextSize. I'm suspecting that I need to play around with android:heigth or something like that, I just can't find the right setting... any idea?

Comment: @blackst0ne you got the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `android:layout_height` in the Textview to `"wrap_content"`.

Comment: I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Besides doing as CodeZero said, add this to the LinearLayout:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Comment: it still remains the same-.

Comment: Really? I dont know why. Try changing fill_parent for wrap_content on the height and width of the TextView

Comment: also set these attribute to the parent and grandparent and grand grandparent ,...